# Can you run PHPUnit if you just download it from Github and link to it in your script

Tags: php, curl, selenium, phpunit

Ive got some custom Selenium scripts working in a similar way that you might use cURL (theirs a ton of js encryption being done on the POST data on the 3rd party site so it actually more complex to reverse engineer them and use cURL), for these Selenium scripts to work they require PHPUnit, ive gone around trying to install it via the Command line / Pear, but for the life of me cant get it to work.

I noticed you can download all the files as a .zip from the [Github page](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/) would i run into trouble if i just downloaded them placed them in the same folder as my selenium scripts and linked them up correctly via `require()` ?

Comment: Wouldn't `PHAR` be even better choice?

Comment: ill have a look into that, thanks

Comment: I recommend using **Composer** to install PHPUnit. That's a modern package manager that allows you to manage all your dependencies in the same place.